# Why don't we use the vendor-names in doctrine-generator and twig-refering?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, bundle, vendor

My question refers to the following two things:

- If we use `console doctrine:generate:entity` to create a entity, it's simple but we don't provide the vendor name Acme.
- If we extend a twig template we make this by using `AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:index.html.twig` without the vendor name Acme.

Normally this will not make any troubles, but imagine you have a bundle with the same name in another vendor-folder.

**Why aren't we using the above with the vendor name?**

Comment: How would you have two bundles with the same name? This will cause conflict as soon as you instanciate it in your `AppKernel` and an error will occur. How is that even possible?

Comment: no it will not, namespaces?

Comment: `[LogicException] Trying to register two bundles with the same name "AcmeFooBundle"` (*thrown by [`Kernel::initializeBundles()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.5/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php#L479)*) you can't create two bundles with the same name

Comment: Well I didn't tested it, but however the question still exists. Why is that impossible to have two Bundles with the same name (namespaces exist exactly for this, I don't see a sense if it will not work)? And further, why is it impossible to refer to the above given examples with vendor-name?

Comment: It just can't, symfony restrict bundle names to be unique. That's why this is a LogicException. I'm unable to explain WHY they made this decision, but I guess your problem is one of the reasons.

Comment: thank you. If there is somebody out there who can explain it to us please let us know.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html.  The bundle naming convention clearly states that the vendor name is the prefix.  So your scenario of duplicate bundle names among different vendors does not apply.  Furthermore, your statement that twig templates are included without vendor names is also technically wrong since the vendor name is part of the bundle name.  Why such a requirement? Makes life easier and you have to start somewhere.